# Modal pop-up is not appearing using asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Modal pop is not appearing using asp.net C# and got one example but that example is not working using asp.net C# web forms.

Below is my design code.

```
<style type="text/css">

body { font: normal normal normal 10px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;    }

 .ui-dialog-osx {
-moz-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px; border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
}
</style>
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    position: ['center', 'top'],
    show: 'blind',
    hide: 'blind',
    width: 400,
    dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
    buttons: {
        "I've read and understand this": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});


setInterval(function () {
    $('#dialog-message').dialog('open');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#dialog-message').dialog('close');
    }, 1000)
}, 2000);

</script>
```

Below is my body design code.

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <p>
        Hello World!
    </p>
    <div id="dialog-message" title="Important information">
        <span class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="float: left;
            margin: 0 7px 0 0;"></span></span>
        <div style="margin-left: 23px;">
            <p>
                We're closed during the winter holiday from 21st of December, 2010 until 10th of
                January 2011.
                <br />
                <br />
                Our hotel will reopen at 11th of January 2011.<br />
                <br />
                Another line which demonstrates the auto height adjustment of the dialog component.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

I am trying working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/92jv0erw/ but popup is not showing only text showing in body.

Comment: have you included the jQuery and jQueryUI scripts in your page? It's not mentioned in your snippets above. You've included the CSS I can see, but no javascript libraries. There's probably an error in your browser console.

Comment: Yes i did not include from where I can get these script. @ADyson

Comment: download from http://jquery.com/ and http://jqueryui.com/ . Or reference from the CDN https://code.jquery.com/

Comment: Can you give live href links. @ADyson

Comment: really? you can't find a file to download by yourself? It's very clearly laid out on the CDN page.

Comment: I added script and download also.   <script src="jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> . Still popup is not coming. @ADyson

Comment: put jquery before jqueryui - jquery is a dependency of jqueryui, so it must load first. And make sure both of them are before any of your own script. Also make sure your own script is either after your markup, or within a document.ready() call. And do a tutorial on jQuery before you go any further, it will help avoid these basic problems.

Comment: and learn to check your browser console for JS errors (press F12). It will help you solve simple problems a lot faster - rather than simply saying "it's not working" you'll be able to report the actual error message and get to the root of the problem.

Comment: jquery-ui.js:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined. @ADyson

Comment: which means you need to add the jquery reference _before_ the jqueryui one in your page

Comment: Thats also added again getting error: Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'. @ADyson

Comment: is your script calling the "open" method positioned _after_ your HTML in the page?

Comment: I dont know, but popup is not working. @ADyson

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124270/discussion-between-zahed-and-adyson).

Comment: "I don't know". Is your call to $.dialog written _below_ your HTML in the page, or not? It must be fairly obvious which part is above and which part is below...

Comment: setInterval(function () {
    $('#dialog-message').dialog('open');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#dialog-message').dialog('close');
    }, 1000)
}, 2000); is this correct declaration and above mention fiddle also. @ADyson

Comment: yes that will create the endlessly repeating opening and closing. But like I keep saying _all_ your javascript needs to be _below_ your HTML for it to work (or enclosed in a document.ready() section). Have you done that or not?

Comment: then why I am getting this error: jquery-3.1.1.js:273 Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'. @ADyson

Comment: I don't know yet, but if you answer my question about the position of the HTML vs javascript code, that will help to eliminate one possibility. Can you please answer this simple question?? And I don't mean in the fiddle, I mean in your real code

Comment: Let come to on chat.. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124270/discussion-between-zahed-and-adyson. @ADyson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from comments and chat, there are a couple of issues in the originally posted code:

1) There's no reference to jQuery or jQuery UI in the original code. The references to those scripts need to be included.

2) The JS code which attempts to set the dialog box up is running before the HTML element it references exists - because the script is above it in the page, the script is executed before the element actually exists in the browser, causing it to fail.
The simplest solution to this is to move the script below the HTML markup. So you should move the `<script type="text/javascript">` block and all its contents to the bottom of the page. A sensible place would be between the `</form>` and `</body>` closing tags.